# How can i visible my ActionBar when DialogFragment is appear in android?

Tags: android

Explanation:
           I open the DialogFragment over my activity.I set the Gravity.TOP in dialog fragment.Now the problem is when DialogFragment is appear my ActionBar is hide behind the DialogFragment.

I want to see my toolbar and my dialog will appear just after the ActionBar.

It is normal mode

[image]

Actually i want like below screen when i click on today's

[image]

5,6,7 and 8 it's list Items which scroll horizontally. I only hide my tabs not toolbar

Comment: can you show screenshot of what you want ?

Comment: Wait for 2 minit i will edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

First Find your ActionBar size
Goto Style>Theme

Then set Top margin to your DialogFragment.